# Image shows on emulator but not on real device

Tags: java, android, image, emulation, device

I'm working on an Android project where I use a custom ListView with an image on the left.
I use Genymotion emulator, which works fine. The image is shown perfectly:
[Screenshot from Genymotion emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilsJI.png)

However, when I use the app on my device (Huawei P8 Lite), nothing is shown: [Screenshot from device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFceZ.png)

I tried to debug the app on my device, the image path exists (otherwise their would be the "No image available" instead) ans is: ***/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20160415_134349_-350854394.jpg***
I went to the Android device monitor and the image exists, but at a slightly different path (mnt/shell/ instead of /storage/, but I don't think this is the real issue, is it ?)
I don't have any "OutOfMemory" error or any other error in the stacktrace.
This is the code I use to show the picture:

```
    if(values.get(position).getImgList().size()==0){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nopics);
    }
    else {
    //getImg() return the path (string) of the first image in a ArrayList of path
        imageView.setImageBitmap(values.get(position).getImg());
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that getImg() return an image as I use the same method when I send the Image to a webservice. The webservice receive the image correctly.
I also have the read/write internal/external storage in my Android Manifest.

EDIT: I forgot the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px">
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="70px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textSize="48px" >
</TextView>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/croixrouge"
    android:src="@drawable/croixrouge"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50px"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/label" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:src="@drawable/modif"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/croixrouge"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/croixrouge"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:src="@drawable/refreshpurple"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/option"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/option"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px" />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:id="@+id/sublabel"
    android:text="@+id/sublabel"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textSize="32px"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

getImg() code:

```
public Bitmap getImg() {
    if(imgList.size() !=0) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgList.get(0));
        return bmp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDIT: How I pick the image:
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent imageData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageData);

```
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Define.ALBUM_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                path = imageData.getStringArrayListExtra(Define.INTENT_PATH);
...
            }
    }
}
```

And later:

```
 r.setImgList(path);
```

Could someone please help me understand why the image is not displayed on a real device ?

Comment: it doesn't fit maybe try this android:scaleType="fitXY" in imageview

Comment: What are the api levels of the emulator and the device?

Comment: The scaleType stuff didn't work, thank you however. Emulator and device are both API 21, device runs on android 5.0.1 and emulator on 5.0.0

Comment: What does `getImg()` return?

Comment: @KNeerajLal the path of the image which is, as I wrote it in my post, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20160415_134349_-350854394.jpg

Comment: hm, sorry I made a mistake. getImg() return the Bitmap, not the path :( I updated my question with the getImg() code. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to load the image with higher resolutions on ImageView. You have to scale it down to multiple sizes (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) to support multiple screen resolutions and dimensions.

Please refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this helper methods to get the real path of your image. In your getImg() method pass the path created from the helper method:

```
public Bitmap getImg() {
    if(imgList.size() != 0) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(imgList.get(0));
        String path = getRealPathFromUri(getActivity(), uri)
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        return bmp;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String path;
    if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        path = getRealPathFromContentURI(context, uri);
    } else if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        path = uri.getPath();
    } else {
        path = uri.toString();
    }
    return path;
}

private String getRealPathFromContentURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    if (contentUri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    if (column_index == -1) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }

    String path;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else {
        path = null;
    }

    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this didn't solve the problem. On the emulator it still works (but it rezise my picture, dunno why) but still the same issue on my Android device

Comment: How do you get the image path that will be saved into values array?

Comment: For your layout code, always use dp value not px to make the size consistent in various android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem !
I scaled the bitmap. It seems like it couldn't fit the screen or something ...

```
public Bitmap getImg() {
    if(imgList.size() !=0) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgList.get(0));
        int nh = (int) ( bmp.getHeight() * (800.0 / bmp.getWidth()) );
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 600, nh, true);
        return scaled;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank you for your help